# SQL Server 2008 - Updating only a specific number of rows within a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, count

I have a table called mytable with a number of columns. 
What I am trying to do is to update a column within that table where 2 colums are matched but only for the first 400 records that match the criteria.

Example:

Columns

```
Name     Ref   ID    Text
```

When ref = 555 and id = 7 I want to update the column called Text with the word 'Matched'. 
I am aware that there will be approx 800 records that match the criteria but I only want to update the first 400.
Can anyone help with this please?

Regards,
Will.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One easy way is using [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in a [`CTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), e.g.:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ref, id),
          ref, id, text
   FROM   MyTable
   WHERE  ref = 555 AND  id = 7
)
UPDATE CTE SET text = 'Matched' 
WHERE RN <= 400
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8868/1/0)

Comment: Tim that worked great, thank you very much and everyone else for your help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the a CTE to select the `TOP 400` rows that have a `ref=555` and an `id=7`:

```
;with cte as
(
  select top 400 ref, id, text
  from yourtable
  where ref = 555
    and id = 7
  order by ref, id
)
update cte
set text = 'Matched';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa83cb/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table you want to update with itself:

```
UPDATE MyTable
        SET Text = 'Matched'
    FROM MyTable
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TOP 400 ID FROM MyTable WHERE ref = 555 AND ID = 7 ORDER BY ID
    ) AS InnerMyTable ON MyTable.ID = InnerMyTable.ID
```

Comment: Presumes that `ID` id the primary key, what if `ref` and `id` is a composite primary key or they are not unique at all?

Comment: Well if that was the case it would be necessary to specify what the first 400 are so yes I presumed that IDs are unique in that table.

Answer (score 0):

I have given update trigger if you need insert change update keyword in second line to insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER T
AFTER UPDATE ON MYTABLE
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
WHERE (SELEC COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE ref = 555 and id = 7) <= 400
BEGIN
UPDATE MYTABLE
SET TEXT = 'MATCHED'
WHERE REF = NEW.REF AND ID = NEW.ID;
END;
```